# How can I maintain image class when using mc:edit in a MailChimp template?

Tags: email, html-email, mailchimp

I'm trying to create a MailChimp template where an image is editable using mc:edit

Here's the code:

```
<img class="flexibleImage" mc:edit="top_image">
```

This seems all good, but once I edit this image using the MailChimp editor, I lose the original class "flexibleImage" and all other class and style info related to that img element.

How can I create a template with an editable image and maintain (or add) that class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else with the problme, this answer is based on a response from MailChimp support:

> It looks like it isn't possible to keep a custom class attached to an
>   editable image.  What you could do instead though is apply the class
>   to the image's containing element.  So if the image is in a `<div>`, add
>   `flexibleImage` to the `div`, and then update your CSS rules to point to
>   `.flexibleImage>img`.

Comment: It looks to me like mailchimp has some weird behaviour: non-editable images preserve the `<img width="123">`, but strips the width-tag from editable images. This breaks the image size in e.g. Outlook.

Comment: @tobias47n9e Do you have a solution for that problem other than using exact-size images?

Comment: @dgBP Not really. Best is probably to look at a different service.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the image you want to edit is inside an `mc:repeatable` block that in turn is inside another `mc:repeatable` block

Answer (score 0):

Even four years later this is still an issue.

The other route is to put `mc:edit` on the parent container, and have images managed through there, but you lose the Image uploader box, which is poor user experience.

You can go into Settings when you have uploaded a new image and put the sizes in there. Not ideal, but Mailchimp is to blame here (no such issue on Campaign Monitor templates).